# Django serializer string to float

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with this field in the serializer:

```
answer_star = DecimalField(max_digits=1, decimal_places=1, blank=True,
                               null=True)
```

I'm passing strings in the payload, e.g. `"4.0"` and this fails at the serializer level:

```
@transaction.atomic
def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
    review = self.get_object(pk)
    questions = request.data.get('questions')
    submitted = request.data.get('submitted')

    if submitted:
        review.update(status='PENDING')

    for updated_question in questions:
        question_id = updated_question.get('id')
        question = ReviewQuestion.objects.filter(pk=question_id)
        question.update(**updated_question)
    return Response()
```

> decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

What's the cleanest approach for converting the `answer_star` field in my `updated_question` payload from a string to a float?

Comment: you post method does not contain any use of serializer.

Comment: @VishalSingh Doesn't a model serializer dictate how fields are saved to the model in the update method?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is inside the for loop, since you already loop over questions:

```
for updated_question in questions:
    updated_question.answer_star = float(updated_question.answer_star)
     # the rest of you code...
```